# Why do not f-strings work in comprehensions inside other f-strings?

Tags: python, f-string

I would like to use an f-string inside a generator which I put inside another f-string, such as here:

```
MORSE_CODE = {'123' : '456', '789' : 'qwe'}
print(f'{(f'{key}, {value}' for key, value in MORSE_CODE.items())}')
```

When this was run I got the next error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-10-05579b450d5e>", line 2
    print(f'{(f'{key}, {value}' for key, value in MORSE_CODE.items())}')
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

At first I thought that it is impossible to use f-strings within generators but, when I put it `(f'{key}, {value}' for key, value in MORSE_CODE.items())` into variable, this worked:

```
a = (f'{key}, {value}' for key, value in MORSE_CODE.items())
print(f'{{{a}}}')

{<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000025EE94EF200>}
```

How does this work in Python? I could not google this information about working f-strings into generators inside another f-strings. What is the difference between these pieces of code?

Comment: This is unrelated to generators, they have nothing to do with it. This is simply about nesting f-strings. Your last snippet has no nesting, your first snippet does.

Comment: what exactly is that you want to achieve? I don't see the point for generator expression inside f-string with another f-string (regardless whether it is possible or not).

Comment: Change one of them to use double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the expected output is, but when making use of the different string quotes `"` and `'` the parser can differentiate between the start of the inner f-string and the end of the outer.

```
MORSE_CODE = {'123' : '456', '789' : 'qwe'}
print(f'{(f"{key}, {value}" for key, value in MORSE_CODE.items())}')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have just found this myself and was typing about this in the moment when you answered. Earlier I thought that expressions inside curly brackets are independent of the outer string.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found unexpectedly that this works perfectly if you use different quotes. I have not expected this because I thought that the expression  inside curly brackets is independent of the string so I can use any quotes but their change solved the problem.

```
MORSE_CODE = {'123' : '456', '789' : 'qwe'}
print(f'{{{(f"{key}, {value}, " for key, value in MORSE_CODE.items())}}}')

{<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000025EE95BEA50>}
```

However, I am curious now why these quotes are dependent?